# Codeigniter template library build or download?

Tags: codeigniter

i am pretty new to CI. been looking at few template libraries but found either they have much more than I need or not enough.
so i started to build my own. is there anything i should keep in mind? in terms of security? caching? etc etc
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template library is pretty simple to create and unless you have a need for all the stuff that one of the many available have I would just roll your own. With that said I tend to use the one by Phil the most as it matches the closest with the way I do things.